# Whats the time cycle for the campsite?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I recently got my campsite and I hardly know anything about it. I know some stuff. Anyway, I got a camper on Monday and since I didn't convince him to move in, he left on Tuesday. I was wondering how many more days will it be until I get another camper? Is there a certain time cycle for villiagers to camp? 
I know, I've asked so many questions on here but I'm new to this game and some stuff is hard to understand...

Answer (score 1):

There is no time cycle to the campsite. According to the [Animal Crossing wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Campsite), if your town doesn't have the maximum of 10 villagers, the campsite will be vacant on any random day.